# How to debug Botframework Webchat workspace code?

Tags: webpack, botframework, lerna

I have cloned [webchat-repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) to test something out. And as mentioned in section [Testing Web Chat for development purpose](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#testing-web-chat-for-development-purpose) I was able to sucessfully start an instance of local webchat.

```
cd packages/playground
npm start
```

I guess this starts a local webpack dev server to serve the files from `${workspaceFolder}/packages/playgroud`. Which in turn uses files from `lib` directories of various other packages.

Now I want to debug this code (hit breakpoints and such..) but I am unable to do so.

[image: Chrome Sources tab]

When I enter `Sources` section of Google Chrome, it shows relevant files in the lib folder of packages, but they are unreadble (i.e. not useful of debuging). Attached an screenshot above.

I am using the VS Code Chrome launch config (lauch config is part of the repo) to attach to the local dev server (which in itself is successful). But VSCode shows `unverified breakpoint` on the breakpoints. I suppose because this is happening because VSCode cannot determine how to map the files served by dev server to the source.

[image: VSCode shows unverified breakpoint]

All I want to do is place a break point in VSCode workspace and hit that breakpoint on some action on the local webchat. How can I do that? If not from the VSCode then atleast from `Sources` tab of Chrome.

I tried changing the Webpack `devtools` options to generate sourcemaps, but that didn't help.

I am developing on Ubuntu 18.04 with VSCode and Node v10. Am I missing some configuration? I do not high familiarity with JS frontend Ecosystem (Webpack, Babel, etc.) so could be that I am doing something silly (or not doing something). **Any help would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem, and I have a workaround but not a fix.

When I need to debug Web Chat code, I actually open up one of the samples (say, 01.a.getting-started-full-bundle and use this as my place to debug.
`serve.json` samples the different Web Chat distributions, and in this example I use `/webchat.js`

1. Navigate to `01.a.getting-started-full-bundle`
2. On `index.html` line 10, change the CDN line to `<script src="/webchat.js"></script>`
3. Change line 35 to use your bot's credentials (or to use Mock Bot, keep this line the same)
4. In Web Chat root folder, run `npm run build:sample` - you only need to do this once
5. Also in root, run `npx serve` or `serve` if you have it globally installed

This will run the page with the Web Chat client and bot on `http://localhost:5000/samples/01.a.getting-started-full-bundle/index.html`
Using `Ctrl + P` will allow you to hit break points, and you can attach the VS Code debugger as well.

[image]